# DAX Statement to Replicate Query Constraints

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have created a dashboard in PBI using a dataflow from a live database. I am trying to replicate the constraints of a query in DAX and am a little lost on how to get the correct DAX syntax/results.

Below is the query:

```
SELECT count(IPID) as theSwitches 
FROM KUB.MVIEW_E_SWITCH 
WHERE (NORMALPOSITIONA = 0 OR NORMALPOSITIONB = 0 OR NORMALPOSITIONC = 0) 
AND (FEEDERID <> FEEDERID2) 
AND FEEDERID2 is not null
```

Here is my DAX:

```
TIE= (MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONA]= 0 || 
MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONB] = 0 || 
MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONC]= 0) 
&& (MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID] <> MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2]) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2]))
```

Here is some dummy data:

```
IPID     NORMALPOSITIONA   NORMALPOSITIONB   NORMALPOSITIONC   FEEDERID    FEEDERID2
123141          1                 1                1             GC21        GC12
145361          0                 0                1              
096842          0                 0                0             BC21        BC32
053912          0                 0                0           
018249          1                 1                1 
827247          0                 1                0             HD32        HD32
```

I know it is not going to count these, but I wanted to just get a true/false column and only count the true values for my report section of the PBIX.

Is Dax the correct language to perform this, or should I look to use M Code in the Power Query Editor? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is measure:

```
TIE = COUNTROWS (CALCULATETABLE(Sheet2, Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONA]= 0 || 
Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONB] = 0 || 
Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONC]= 0 
&& (Sheet2[FEEDERID] <> Sheet2[FEEDERID2]) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet2[FEEDERID2]))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help with this! I am getting the same issue as you. It is counting `IPID` 53912 even though `FEEDERID2` is blank. `IPID` 145361 shouldn't be counted because `FEEDERID2` is blank. It is like it is still counting rows even when `FEEDERID2` is blank.

Comment: I forgot about the parentheses over OR statement. Add and try again.
(Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONA]= 0 || 
Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONB] = 0 || 
Sheet2[NORMALPOSITIONC]= 0 )

Comment: `COUNTROWS (CALCULATETABLE(MVIEW_E_SWITCH, MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONA]= 0 || 
MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONB] = 0 || 
MVIEW_E_SWITCH[NORMALPOSITIONC]= 0 
&& (MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID] <> MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2]) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(MVIEW_E_SWITCH[FEEDERID2]))))` 


I am getting an error saying the expression contains multiple columns, but only a singled column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try the following solution if it helps please mark it as the answer.

1. Create a calculated column with the following DAX:

   ```
   Open FID2 =
   IF (
      AND(
          (Table[NPA] = 0 || Table[NPB] = 0 || Table[NPC] = 0 )
           && NOT ( ISBLANK ( Table[FEEDERID2] ) ),
                  Table[FEEDERID] <> Table[FEEDERID2]
           ),
      TRUE (),
      FALSE ()
       )
   ```

[image: Output]

Comment: So, this is giving me the same count as my original DAX statment, but my SQL statement is giving me 991.... UGH! Thank you for your help on this though.

Comment: If this helped you then please mark it answer so that others can find it easily. Thanks.